# Order mysql results by field value

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to filter my results from my query in order X column name...

I have the following...

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM directory
                        WHERE user_active != '' 
                          AND County = :county 
                       ORDER BY' . $row['Date'] .'" );
```

I want to get all my results and order them from the value in the date column, this is stored as XX/XX/XXXX

Can anybody see what im doing wrong?

Comment: If your date is stored as a string, then that is wrong.  Dates should be stored in the native format so they will work in `order by`.

Comment: In most occasions it is more advisable to store timestamps on the database fields.

Comment: Ive amended my upload and DB to keep dates in the date format @jap1968, how would i order by?

Answer (score 1):

What is `$row['Date']`? You can only order by column name or column index(1, 2, 3, ...) like

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM directory WHERE user_active != '' AND County = :county ORDER BY date" );
```

Also, your query misses a space behind the ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

Both Gordon, and AmShegar have provided you with a clue as to why this does not work.

To order your results by the date, simply go:

```
SELECT <fields>
FROM <table>
ORDER BY <datefield>
```

And you can suffix that with "ASC" or "DESC" depending on whether you want older dates first, or newer ones.  This all assumes that the date field is, in fact, a date field.

Comment: Ive tried this @Moo-Juice only no luck...

  $sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM directory WHERE user_active != '' AND County = :county ORDER BY Date DESC");

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
$sth = $conn->prepare
        ("SELECT 
            * 
        FROM directory 
        WHERE user_active != '' 
        AND County = :county 
        ORDER BY '.$row['Date'].'

        DATE_FORMAT('$row['Date']','%m-%d-%Y'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ordering by specific field values must do `FIELD( )`

in your example

```
  $sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM directory
                    WHERE user_active != '' 
                      AND County = :county 
                   ORDER BY FIELD( date , '.$row['Date'].')   " ); 
                                     ^---------------------------------column name    
                                                  ^^-------------------field value
```

[exemple here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/)